# Optimizing MySQL query removing subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Having these tables:

```
customers
---------------------
`id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NOT NULL,
....

customers_subaccounts
-------------------------
`companies_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`customers_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`subaccount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
```

I need to get all the customers whom have been assigned more than one subaccount for the same company.

This is what I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT customers_id 
     FROM customers_subaccounts
     GROUP BY customers_id, companies_id 
     HAVING COUNT(subaccount) > 1)
```

This query is too slow though. It's even slower if I add the **DISTINCT** modifier to *customers_id* in the SELECT of the subquery, which in the end retrieves the same customers list for the whole query. Maybe there's a better way without subquerying, anything faster will help, and I'm not sure whether it will retrieve an accurate correct list.

Any help?

Comment: I think that it's your `COUNT` that takes too much time. The `WHERE .. IN` is pretty slow too, but you can improve it by using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Hearner Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, I'm aware of it. It was due to the subquery actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the subquery with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customers_id 
    FROM customers_subaccounts
    GROUP BY customers_id, companies_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.customers_id
```

Comment: Your suggestion is the faster one (around 0.023 secs without caching). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using `EXISTS()` which may be faster then a join :

```
SELECT * FROM customers t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM customers_subaccounts s
             WHERE s.customers_id = t.id
             GROUP BY s.customers_id, s.companies_id 
             HAVING COUNT(subaccount) > 1)
```

You should also considering adding the following indexes(if not exists yet) :

```
customers_subaccounts (customers_id,companies_id,subaccount)
customers (id)
```

Comment: Your query is too slow as well. Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want *different* subaccounts for the company (or that they are guaranteed to be different anyway), then the following could be faster under some circumstances:

```
select c.*
from (select distinct cs.customers_id
      from customers_subaccounts cs join
           customers_subaccounts cs2
           on cs.customers_id = cs2.customers_id and
              cs.companies_id = cs2.companies_id and
              cs.subaccount < cs2.subaccount
     ) cc join
     customers c
     on c.customers_id = cc.customers_id;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `customers_subaccounts(customers_id, companies_id, subaccount)`.

Note:  This assumes that the `subaccounts` are different for the rows you want.  What is really needed is a way of defining unique rows in the `customers_subaccounts` table.

Comment: I've tried it and it's definitely much faster than mine. But you have to correct the last line, which I think should be  **on c.id = cc.customers_id**. It retrieves the same results as mine, and faster.

Comment: I've checked it's not as faster as Tim Biegeleisen's suggestion. Yours lasts around 0.043 secs

Comment: @user3514092 . . . I assume you have the stated index for the performance comparison.  Tim's answer is also a very good answer (I upvoted it before I answered).  In some circumstances this can be faster, because it does not require two levels of aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Try following;)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN customers_subaccounts t2 ON t1.id = t2.customers_id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t2.companies_id
HAVING COUNT(t2.subaccount) > 1
```

Also you may add `index` on `customers_id`.

Comment: I get this error: Column 'subaccount' in having clause is ambiguous

Comment: Updated. Check again please.

Comment: mmm, it's slow (took me 42.74 secs) and it retrieves repeated customers.

Comment: What if using `INNER JOIN` like my updated answer? @user3514092

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to speed up the query by using cache the sub-query result. A simple change in your query aware mysql that can cache the sub-query result:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE id IN 
  (select * from
    (SELECT distinct customers_id 
     FROM customers_subaccounts
     GROUP BY customers_id, companies_id 
     HAVING COUNT(subaccount) > 1) t1);
```

I used it many years ago and it helped me very much.

Comment: You mean by enclosing a third-level subquery as an alias it will cache the result? That's interesting because it's still very similar to my query. I've tried it and it's really fast (around 0.027 secs).

Comment: You're welcome. Yes. In the first time it was interesting for me too.